# Junit Mockito:How to Pass parameters: Arraylist,int value to Rest Junit API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing junit for a rest API , I have junit test method with below snippet , Can any one tell me how we can pass the ArrayList and int type of data when we are using mockito. Can you please tell me.
Test invocation eg:

```
`   List<MyUser> myUserList = new ArrayList<MyUser>();
    MyUser user1 = new UsrHelper().create();
    MyUser user2 = new UsrHelper().create();
    myUserList.add(user1);
    myUserList.add(user2);
    MvcResult result =mockMvc.perform(post("/test1/test2/test3").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(JsonUtils.toJsonString(myUserList)).param("myuserId", 1234).param("id", "abcd123")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();`
```

In the above myUserList is the arraylist and myuserId - is int value. Please let me know.

Comment: Send everything in a single JSON object

Comment: Hi, I have to pass it seperately as two parameters as the rest api method has two params. pls let me know.

Comment: Hi, I got the soultion , the mapping parameter was passed correctly. Wrong parameter name (myuserId) was passed. Got fixed the problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the soultion , the mapping parameter was passed correctly. Wrong parameter name (myuserId) was passed. Got fixed the problem.Thank you